# Smooth Scrolling throughout the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make my website scroll smoother throughout the entire website, not just jump from a link to an anchor. Ive been googling about it but i have not found the solution im looking for. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a the script you mean, I use it on my own website: https://www.paradoxis.nl.
Just save the file and try it out, it **only works on chrome** tough.

URL: https://gist.github.com/galambalazs/6477177

```
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/galambalazs/6477177/raw/b2a85bb7f79b2721600677525a16a17bc511f1b8/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function this is working for smooth scroll.

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

don't need to create anything just put this code into your js file it's working automatically.

for more details.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that script is for only jumping from a link/anchor to another link/anchor. I want my scrolling to be smooth without clicking a link/anchor.